# Google cloud and django wagtail getting database error on deployed website

Tags: python, django, database, google-cloud-platform, wagtail

I'm deploying django wagtail website on google cloud successfully, but I'm getting: "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details." error. I even tried hardcoding database values in settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'url to sql stuff',
        'USER': 'user I register',
        'PASSWORD': "my password",
        'PORT': '8080',
        'HOST': "127.0.0.1"
        }
}
```

I can confirm values are correct and database exists on cloud. Still getting the same error. What should I do?

UPDATE: Full error traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/views.py", line 14, in serve
    site = Site.find_for_request(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/sites.py", line 150, in find_for_request
    site = Site._find_for_request(request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/sites.py", line 160, in _find_for_request
    site = get_site_for_hostname(hostname, port)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/sites.py", line 23, in get_site_for_hostname
    sites = list(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 320, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1348, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 573, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 64, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 55, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 284, in get_select
    sql, params = self.compile(col)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 496, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 948, in as_sql
    sql = ".".join(map(compiler.quote_name_unless_alias, identifiers))
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 487, in quote_name_unless_alias
    r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Comment: If you have multiple settings files, then this might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
'NAME': 'url to sql stuff',
'PORT': '8080',
'HOST': "127.0.0.1"
```

Unless you have you have some sort of tunnel set up so that your database is accessible via localhost, I don't think any of these 3 parameters are correct. The [documentation says you can use private IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/private-ip) to connect to your database but I don't think they include localhost. The default port for postgres is 5432. And name should be the database name, not a url.